# MySQL Not Recovered After Running Out of Space

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I've got a MySQL 5.7.26 running on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm running an app that's loading a few GB data into the database, which was running fine until I let the root volume (with MySQL on) run out of space - I let a ton of application log files build up - after which MySQL started timing out transactions. This is just a dev server, so is pretty small and not closely monitored.

Anyway, I've since deleted all the log files and restarted MySQL and my app, but it's not back to its old self. The transactions aren't being timed out, but they are taking ages (used to be sub-second, now up to 45s). I'm guessing that running out of disk space has put MySQL in an odd state, meaning it still thinks it's not got space to grow data or log files.

So is there something I can to do to "recover" MySQL? To tell it that it can start expanding files again? Thanks!

Comment: What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` say?  MyISAM or InnoDB?  Which log files were deleted?  How much free disk space now?  `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to repair the table (or tables) with:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "repair table <tablename>"
```